# What is Rails ActiveRecord find(x) method that is equivalent to a lazy-evaluated-scope? How to refactor ActiveRecord finder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, refactoring

Is Rails' find(x) method on a model lazy? If not, what is the equivalent?

I am new to Rails, so I found myself writing scopes like this:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_instructor_id, lambda { |instructor_id| where(:instructor_id => instructor_id) }
  scope :by_course_template_id, lambda { |course_template_id| where(:course_template_id => course_template_id ) }
  scope :by_company_id, lambda { |company_id| joins(:instructor).merge(CompanyUser.by_company_id(company_id)) }
end
```

It's not a lot of work, but now I'm asking myself... if Rails provided these with a scope, I wouldn't have to write them.

So, does Rails offer them? Can I do something like the below code and only make it do 1 database call?

```
Company.find(params[:id]).instructors.courses
```

instead of

```
Course.by_company_id(params[:id])
```

Which is correct? I know `Course.by_company_id(params[:id])` is only 1 database call. It is very familiar to writing SQL or queries in Hibernate. But if you can write it the other way, maybe one should?

However, I don't want to write `Company.find(params[:id]).instructors.courses` if it results in more than 1 database call. I can see the advantage though because it means never having to write the 3 scopes I showed you above, but I am worried that `Company.find(x)` is not lazy. Is it?

Comment: I don't think this question has been answered yet :( If you'd like to answer it, please read the comments below to see what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `#scoped` method on a model before calling `#find`:

```
user = User.scoped.instructors.courses.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Umm... it could just be me... but your query doesn't look like it does the same thing. Are you saying to use `Company.scoped.find(params[:id]).instructors.courses` ? Why didn't the Rails team just make `find(params[:id])` lazy by default if that's the solution? Seems like `.scoped` is unnecessary complexity and adds inconsistency with the rest of ActiveRecord. I understand if that's how to do it... but it just seems like an exception to the rule for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

To make `find` by id query lazy  you can add new method to your controller and then add this method as helper.

```
# company
def company  
  @company ||= Company.find(params[:id])  
end  
helper :company

#view
<%= company.name %>
```

To get more information you can check great RailsCast - [Decent Exposure](http://railscasts.com/episodes/259-decent-exposure)

Comment: No, that's not what I mean either. I'm talking about lazy-evaluation of sql so that your entire One-line query happens in 1 Database call, not in 2 database calls... or N+1 database calls, etc.

Comment: You can use `includes`:
`def company  
  @company ||= Company.includes(:instructors, :courses).find(params[:id])
end `

but theres no other way to do less queries.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I had in mind either. I think maybe the way I am making the queries in my question IS the correct answer possibly. Maybe it's a bit more work and isn't as pretty, but it's probably the most efficient way to write it.